# How to make App Events work in Events Manager. IOS 14.5+

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-analytics

The overview tab displays actions such as install, open, buy. But there is no data about the percentage of ATE devices for IOS 14.5+.

And so also in event testing. Nothing shows up.

Looked all over the internet, couldn't find any solutions for the new version of Facebook SDK.